# Compressing and loading nodejs components efficiently

Tags: node.js, gzip

Is there a way to load the node.js `bower components` and `node modules` efficiently i.e. in as much less time as possible?Every time when the user opens the app for the 'first time' it takes ages to download the components and render the page.

Currently it is taking around 10-15 seconds to get downloaded when we run the application for the first time which is not at all good!

I tried using **gzip compression** but failed to use it efficiently.

Any help with the process or method would be great!

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

You would usually not want to deliver the individual files to the users. 
Instead you can use a tool that minifies and bundles your dependencies. This will lead to the users only needing to download one minified file (usually called `vendor.js` or something similar) that contains all the javascript needed. This reduces the number of requests and saves time.

You might want to take a look at grunt or other build tools as a possible solution for your problem. Here is a [basic example](https://egghead.io/lessons/grunt-minifying-your-output-with-grunt-uglify)

Comment: can we somehow check the components and modules that the applications uses and remove the unused?